# position button in window depending on window size

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating this game in Visual Studio for my school project using SFML to render and create sprite.
I have created this button which I currently places at
x=1000, y = 600 on my screen size.
I have retina display macbook.

I tested the position of the button and it changes it's location depending on the screen size. if the screen size is something smaller then my x and y then button would not even show on the screen so how would i make it dynamic for all the different screens and how can i make it scale to the same size in different sizes.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with sf::VideoMode::GetDesktopMode() to determine the size of the desktop you're running on and divide/multiply your button coordinates appropriately. You could also approach the scaling problem with sf::Views - http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-view.php